How to publish a springboot project in mavenlocal and use that jar in another springboot project both project are using gradle?
I have an id-generator-client project which I have successfully published in mavenLocal and I have to use that jar in another project eApplication. Followed all the steps I found on Google but my eApplication can't find that jar. Here are the screenshots.
id-generator-client & eApplication setting.gradle & build.gradle images are provided.
Setting.gradle id-generator-client
build.gradle id-generator-client.
build.gradle eApplication.

Have you checked in your local repository what was actually exported? If you are not able to include the artifact in another application you probably have wrong coordinates.

How exactly do you publish to mavenLocal? Have you confirmed that the Artifact is located in the corresponding folder? What is the exact error message you are getting?

Its probably not sufficient to just include the publish plugin, you should also configure it, e.g.:
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.example'
            artifactId = 'id-generation-client'
            version = '1.0'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}

You may also remove the groupId and version, it might get picked up automatically.

Thanks the issue is resolved. I didn't knew had to do this as well.
